# Dynamic form generation and processing with pre-filled java script arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, timer, radio-button

I have  an array of questions(Q[i]) and four options each(op[]).
I have populated the data into it from mysql.

1. I wish to generate a dynamic form, below is the code for it, it is not working, let me know how to go about.

I wish to make a quiz something like 
http://www.w3schools.com/quiztest/quiztest.asp?qtest=PHP

Here is the code which I tried :

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
    {
        <form name="Quiz Test">
        document.write(Q[i]+"</br>");
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value=op1[i]> document.write(op1[i])<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value=op2[i]> document.write(op2[i])<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value=op3[i]> document.write(op3[i])<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value=op4[i]> document.write(op4[i])<br>
        //<input type="submit" onclick="get_radio_value()">
        </form>
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [PHP JSON](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to fill the array

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.questionDiv { display:none }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
// the array below is of course fillable on the server. 
// Just dump the array to JSON
// var quiz = <?PHP echo $someJSON ?>    
var quiz = [
{"Q":"How ....","A":["one","two","three","four"]},
{"Q":"How ....","A":["one","two","three","four"]},
{"Q":"How ....","A":["one","two","three","four"]},
{"Q":"How ....","A":["one","two","three","four"]},
{"Q":"How ....","A":["one","two","three","four"]}
]; // note no comma after the last
function next(idx) {
  document.getElementById('Q'+idx).style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('Q'+(idx+1)).style.display='block';
}
window.onload=function() {
  var html = "";
  for(var i=0,n=quiz.length;i<n;i++) {
    html += '<div class="questionDiv" id="Q'+i+'"><span class="question">'+(i+1)+'. '+quiz[i].Q+'</span><br />'
    var answer = quiz[i].A;
    for (var j = 0, m=answer.length;j<m;j++) {
      var ident = 'A'+i+'_'+j;
      html += '<input type="radio" name="'+ident+'" id="'+ident+'" value="'+j+'" /><label for="'+ident+'">'+(j+1)+'. '+answer[j]+'</label><br />';
    }
    if (i<quiz.length-1) html += '<input type="button" onclick="next('+i+')" value="Next"/>';
    else html += '<input type="submit" />';
    html += '</div>'
  }
  document.getElementById('quizDiv').innerHTML=html;
  document.getElementById('Q0').style.display='block';
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="answer.php">
<div id="quizDiv">
</div>
</body>
</form>
<html>
```

Comment: Well the problem is I donot want to fill up the array on my own. I want the process to be dynamic. As mentioned, i have mysql database from where i populate the Q and the options array randomly. Thats why the trouble. Well do you think this is the correct approach or using jquery would make things easier. Thanks for the reply

Comment: JQuery can be used but will have exactly the same issue, filling up the array. Hence the array I gave you is ridiculously easy to fill on the server. PHP even has JSON http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Comment: i already have the arrays filled. questions in Q[] and options in op1[], op2,op3,op4 and answer in ans[] array. I want to calculate and report the result on the client side itself (using some on_click handler)

Comment: the next thing i did not understand is how do i fill the var quiz[]. from those 5 arrays of mine and check the answer. please suggest any good source(NOT VERY DETAILED) that might be helpful for understanding the stuff as well. im a newbie. thanks a lot!!

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question with PHP tag - I am a javascripter and to output the array I suggest from your arrays is trivial for a PHP person for example using foreach or some combination of explode. http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php . Send the results to the server and check agains your answer array. You should not have the answers in the source of the web page to avoid cheating